# Failed assertion: line 24 pos 15: 'initialCameraPosition != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, maps

I have inserted below library in `pubspec.yaml`

```
  google_maps_flutter:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/flutter/plugins
      path: packages/google_maps_flutter
```

But I get an error every time

`Another exception was thrown: 'file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/git/plugins-aedcc6f81843ae2da3a6ac0c8e8c4b530d1ac035/packages/google_maps_flutter/lib/src/google_map.dart': Failed assertion: line 24 pos 15: 'initialCameraPosition != null': is not true.`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

just use initialCameraPosition in GoogleMap()
for example :

```js
GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(51.5160895, -0.1294527),),
            )
```